# given certain date, how to get the first day of previous month with the same weekday in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm a noob using mysql, and a search here and in google didn't help me much with this.

I need to  obtain the first day of previous month of certain date with the same weekday

example: given this date: May 29th  of 2015 (friday), I need the first friday of April (April 3rd of 2015).

(bear in mind, I need that value inside an update (specifically, inside a where))

Thanks for your help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows one way to get there. If you can't use or don't want the intermediate variables, simply replace them with the repeated SQL.

```
SET @startdate= '2015-04-06';
SET @firstdayofprevmon =
 CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_ADD(@startdate, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)),'-',LPAD(MONTH(DATE_ADD(@startdate, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)),2,'0'),'-01' ) ;
 SELECT
CASE
 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@firstdayofprevmon) <  DAYOFWEEK(@startdate) THEN
 /* If the day of week for first day of previous month is less than target day of week,simply increment the difference */
 DATE_ADD(@firstdayofprevmon, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(@startdate)-DAYOFWEEK(@firstdayofprevmon)) DAY) 

 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@firstdayofprevmon) >  DAYOFWEEK(@startdate) THEN
  /* If greater, add a week to the difference */
 DATE_ADD(@firstdayofprevmon, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(@startdate)-DAYOFWEEK(@firstdayofprevmon) +7)  DAY) 
 ELSE
 /* Otherwise, the first day of the month is the answer */
 @firstdayofprevmon
 END AS TargetDate
```